# Do particular zombies have any impact on the chance to drop items/coins?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I have asked about the [chances of an item being dropped](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209034/what-is-the-chance-of-getting-a-zen-garden-plant) in PvZ1 before, but i was wondering, do certain types of zombies have an effect on this?

I was watching a speedrun of the game, and when they reached the Bobsled Bonanza minigame, the bobsled zombies [really came out in force](https://youtu.be/3zKYb9qN4Zc?t=24384)!

So I was wondering, is this a potential farming technique for money or items? Or do certain Zombies (like the Bobsled Zombies) have less/no chance to drop items?